# How to include zip files with a similar name in a path (powershell)

Tags: powershell

Greetings i have this script (the one shown below) and i want to include all zip files from this directory that include acc in their name. And while i use wildcard it says that $path contains invalid characters.

Any ideas?

```
$Path = "\\fas270_ctrl1\Cifs\INP_OUT_DIAS_PROXY_FILES\*ACC*.*" 

$descriptions = "*ACC*.FAO" 

$Filter = $descriptions

$OutPath = 'C:\results'

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem 

$zip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($Path) 

$zip.Entries | 
  Where-Object { $_.FullName -like $Filter } |
  ForEach-Object { 

    $FileName = $_.Name
    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::ExtractToFile($_, "$OutPath\$FileName", $true)
    }

$zip.Dispose()
```

explorer $OutPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify an absolute path to the file(s) for the `OpenRead` method (no wildcards). Relative paths are interpreted as relative to (.NET) the current working directory, but that may not be the same path as is current for PowerShell..

I also recommend using the `Join-Path` cmdlet to combine the output path with the file name to make sure you don't miss out on backslashes or add too many of these.

Something like this:

```
$Path         = "\\fas270_ctrl1\Cifs\INP_OUT_DIAS_PROXY_FILES"
$descriptions = "*ACC*.FAO"
$Filter       = $descriptions
$OutPath      = 'C:\results'

# make sure the output path exists and if not, create it
if (!(Test-Path -Path $OutPath -PathType Container)) {
    $null = New-Item -Path $OutPath -ItemType Directory
}

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem 

foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter '*ACC*.zip' -File))  {  # you may want to add switch -Recurse
    $zip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($file.FullName) 
    $zip.Entries | Where-Object { $_.Name -like $Filter } | ForEach-Object {
        $fileOut = Join-Path -Path $OutPath -ChildPath $_.Name
        [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::ExtractToFile($_, $fileOut, $true)
    }
    $zip.Dispose()
}
```

Hope that helps